# To what atomic number have they been able to model accurately in the Standard Model?

Tags: atomic-physics, standard-model, subatomic

I'm an electrical engineer.  I took only a little bit of modern physics.  One sophomore level intro course and one course in solid state physics, I guess I took a course in astrophysics also.  But no physics major course in QM or particle physics.  In solid state, we did the particle in a box and a particle with a finite potential energy barrier.

Besides the particle in a box, and the sorta pendulum model (oscillator), and the particle and a barrier, I got to see Schrodinger's equation applied to the hydrogen atom and that was bitchy enough, mathematically.

So what atoms can the Standard Model, with its 25 fundamental constants (according to [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/constants.html)), accurately model?  i presume we've done helium and maybe lithium, i dunno.

What is the highest atomic number of atoms have they quantitatively modeled really good?

If this list includes carbon and oxygen (I wouldn't expect it to), then I have a question to ask regarding this [Triple alpha process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process#Improbability_and_fine-tuning) thing.

So, in addition, may I ask if anyone using the Standard Model, has been able to simulate in a computer the *"cooking of elements"* done in stars?  like a simulation of beryllium and helium getting cooked up into carbon (with an excited state)?

Comment: I've tried to answer you below, but in regards to the triple alpha process, it does not seem related to the standard model. The triple alpha process was found experimentally, and nucleai at that energy scale are probably best described non-relativistically, so "the standard model" is not the right tool for the job. For instance, go to 14.12.3 on http://www.eng.famu.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/style_a/ntsm.html to see the shell model applied to Oxygen. I'm guessing that's good enough to model various details of triple alpha too.

Comment: somehow, those energy levels for the first excited state ${}^{12}\mathrm{C}$ of 7.656 MeV and the energy levels for the ground states of  ${}^{8}\mathrm{Be}$ and ${}^{4}\mathrm{He}$ should be able to be derived from the fundamental physics and descriptions of the atoms so that the experimental results confirm the theoretical result.  what physics would govern this.  pretty much, i thought that we read that all of reality (that we know of) is described by either SM or GR and this is not GR.

Comment: You are basically talking about a calculational problem now. We have no evidence for any further interactions in nature beyond SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) and gravity, but that doesn't mean we can actually predict every single energy level in a complicated system like a carbon atom from first principles. It's a bit like asking a microbiologist to derive the basic nutritional requirements for a human. Yeah, we have all the basic information *in principle*, but it's too difficult to calculate in a finite period of time or with current techniques.

Comment: okay, this last comment address and answers my question.  so we can't (yet) do what i was inquiring about for carbon.  i'm pretty sure we've been able to derive energy levels some of the smaller atoms, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very sweeping overview of an answer - the standard model does not really describe *any* nuclear interactions. When you talk about the particle in the box and Schrodinger's equations, those are *not* what most people would describe as "the standard model". The Standard Model describes fundamental interactions - between quarks, gluons, leptons (electrons), and force-carrying bosons (W, Z, and Higgs). To describe the nucleus of an atom from first principles, we would need to at least be able to do so with the proton and neutron - which until recently was not possible, because we didn't know their exact particle content. Now, using lattice QCD (a particular approximate numerical technique) it is possible to model both protons, neutrons, and other simple baryons (See the paper link in the comments below). "Is lattice QCD part of the standard model?" is a question beyond the scope of my answer.

So that's a literal interpretation of your question, taking "The Standard Model" to be first principles + constants (25 of them, by one accounting). But if we add to this some particular approximations we can get nuclei, and if we add to this effective field theory + particle content which forms the basis for nuclear models (liquid drop and shell, for instance), we can accurately describe a significant portion of the periodic table.

What does "significant portion" mean? Well, that also depends what you mean by "accurately", but for instance, there is a package called "FLYCHK" (which I just learned about from Google) which can model plasmas of atoms up to Z=26 (Iron).

Comment: you misread what i meant to say.  Shrodinger equation is QM.  but isn't QM part of the standard model?  or something that reduces to QM?  because i keep reading that the Standard Model is the current description of everything atomic and subatomic.  i thought for sure that QM is part of the Standard Model.

Comment: Well, I would consider QM to be a set of principles, whereas "the standard model" is a set of principles plus fundamental constants plus symmetries. But, as sets of principles, SM does reduce to QM in the appropriate limits. I interpreted your question as asking about first principles, and we cannot describe *any* atoms from first principles, because we need to use the parton model for the proton, which comes from experimental evidence and phenomenology.

Comment: For clarity, I should have used "Quantum Field Theory" (QFT) as the set of principles which reduces to QM in the appropriate limits. Add particle content to QFT and you get the standard model, and if you add particle content to QM you get models in nuclear physics.

Comment: thank you.  now is it possible to quantitatively model carbon atoms with QFT or is this atom with all of its particles too formidable to model?

Comment: more basically, can we model a proton ab-initio in QFT? http://science.sciencemag.org/content/347/6229/1452

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams Ah great! I am aware of this project but not it's success. So, I can amend my statements to include modeling of both nuclei and simple baryons!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I will shortly amend my answer based on the paper linked above, but it appears that although we can model protons, neutrons, and simple baryons using QFT (lattice QCD, technically), we can't model something like a carbon atom.